# RGB TO HSI PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo esta funcion:

```
def RGB_TO_HSI(R,G,B):
    if(0<=R<=255 and 0<=G<=255 and 0<=B<=255):
    d = float(R + G + B)
    r = float(R)/d
    g = float(G)/d
    b = float(B)/d
    numerador = float( 0.5 * ((r - g) + (r - b)))
    denominador = float(((r - g) * (r - g) + (r - b) * (g - b))**(0.5))
    if(b < = g):
        h = math.acos(numerador / denominador )
    if(b > g):
        h = (2*math.pi) -  math.acos(numerador/denominador )
     s = 1 - (3 * min(r,g,b))
     i = float(R + G+ B)/float(3*255)
     H = h*(180/math.pi)
     S = s*100
     I = i*255
     return H
     return S
     return I
```

Y cuando trato de ejecutar me sale este error:

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

No entiendo a que se refiere, si es por index o por algo mas, si alguien me pudiera indicar que podria hacer lo agradeceria.

El error es en la linea `d = float(R+G+B)`
Gracias

Comment: En general el código no está bien indentado. Ya que Python no tiene llaves para delimintar dónde empieza y acaba un bloque de código, usa la indentación (o sea, el número de espacios por la izquierda) para ello. El cuerpo de un `if` (la secuencia de instrucciones a ejecutar si se cumple la condición) ha de estar indentado (es decir, más espacios que la línea del `if`). Todas las líneas que compongan ese cuerpo deben llevar la misma indentación (número de espacios por la izquierda) y después regresar a la indentación original (la que tenía el `if`).

Comment: Veo otro problema tras la línea `h=...`. Las líneas siguientes no tienen la misma indentación que la `h`, pero tampoco la misma que el `if`, por lo que no se sabe si son parte del cuerpo del `if` o no. Además tu función tiene tres `return` ¿cómo es eso? En cuanto se ejecute el primero ya no se ejecutarán los demás. Quizás querías poner `return (H,S,I)`.